# Create LineScan image using area scan video

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I'am trying to create an application which will draw an image from a video file. Objective is to create a line scan image using a video stream or video file where each 1px of horizontal line of the picturebox playing the video will be scanned and created into an image.

I found the exact solution here : http://heynicedomain.com/posts/line-camera/
But its in c++ and im not very proficient in c++, im trying to convert the code into c#.

Can anyone help me to convert just the part where image is created if it crosses the line. I have been able to play the video using emgucv, create a vertical line on the picture box.

Here is the code in c++

```
        #include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
 
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 3) {
    cout << "Something's wrong with the provided parameters..." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Usage: ./lineScan   streamType streamLocation" << endl << endl;
    cout << "streamType - 0 = file, 1 = camera" << endl;
    cout << "streamLocation - path to the video stream" << endl;
 
    return 0;
  }
  
  int streamType = atoi(argv[1]);
  string videoStreamLocation = argv[2];
     
  VideoCapture vcap;
  Mat image;
  
  if (streamType == 0) { 
    if(!vcap.open(videoStreamLocation)) {
      cout << "Error opening video stream" << endl;
 
      return 0;
    }
  }
  else {
    if(!vcap.open(atoi(argv[2]))) {
      cout << "Error opening video stream" << endl;
 
      return 0;
    }   
     
    vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);
    vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
  }
 
  namedWindow ("line", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
     
  long frame = 0;
 
  Mat lineImage = Mat::zeros(Size(640, 480), CV_8UC3);
  Mat combinedImage = Mat::zeros(Size(1280, 480), CV_8UC3);
    
  while(true) {
    if(!vcap.read(image)) {
      cout << "No frame" << std::endl;
      return 0;
    }
     
    if (streamType == 0) {
      Mat imageScaled(Size(640, 480), image.type());
     
      resize(image, image, imageScaled.size());
    }
   
    line(image, Point(image.cols / 2 + 1, 0),
                Point(image.cols / 2 + 1, image.rows - 1),
                Scalar(255, 0, 128));
 
    if (frame >= lineImage.cols) {
      lineImage.colRange(1, lineImage.cols - 1).copyTo(lineImage.colRange(0, lineImage.cols - 2));
      image.col(image.cols / 2).copyTo(lineImage.col(lineImage.cols - 2));
    }
    else {
      image.col(image.cols / 2).copyTo(lineImage.col(frame));
    }
     
    image.colRange(0, image.cols - 1).copyTo(combinedImage.colRange(0, image.cols - 1));
    lineImage.colRange(0, image.cols - 1).copyTo(combinedImage.colRange(image.cols, combinedImage.cols - 1));
   
    imshow("line", combinedImage);
     
    frame ++;
     
    stringstream ss;
 
    ss.fill('0');
    ss.width(4);
 
    ss << frame << ".jpg";
     
    /*imwrite(ss.str().c_str(), combinedImage);*/
         
    if(waitKey(1) >= 0) waitKey(0);
  }  
}
```

Comment: you're supposed to *copy* a line (a row or a col) from the cam image, not to draw one ...

Comment: I tried to copy the Matrix lineimage column range, but colsrange of Mat is not available in c#